# How to join the output of two commands when using find -exec?

Tags: shell, find

I have the following code:

```
find . -exec stat --format='%n,%x,%y,%z,' \; 2>&1 | tee output_sasdata_file_info.txt
```

I wanted the `du -k` command to be executed and saved to the txt right after the `%z,`

Tried doing it like this but it's just running the `du -k` command and ignoring the stat

```
find . -exec stat --format='%n,%x,%y,%z' find . -exec du -k,; \; 2>&1 | tee output_sasdata_file_info.txt
```

Example of desired output:

```
./sas/anual.sas7bdat.gz,2020-03-04 11:21:59.648155603 -0300,2020-03-04 11:21:59.845155836 -0300,2021-02-01 16:40:26.542568391 -0350,2656546
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run two commands whose output is combined into a single line,  you'll need to use `-exec` to execute a single shell that runs both commands.

```
find . -exec sh -c \
  'for f; do stat --format="%n,%x,%y,%z,$(du -k "$f")" "$f"; done' \
  _ {} +
```

Some notes of explanation:

1. When using `-c`, the first argument following the shell command is used to set `$0`. I usually use a dummy value of `_` when I don't care what `$0` is set to.
2. `-exec ... {} +` will pass as many matches as possible to the command being run.
3. The loop in the `-c` argument iterates over the files passed to the shell by `find` in this invocation.
4. `du -k "$f"` is run first to construct the format string to be used when `stat ... "$f"` is called. (I am assuming that the argument to `du` will be a single file, not a directory, as otherwise you are going to get a list of results that won't fit nicely into the line you are trying to construct.)

Comment: hello, thanks a lot for the help. It so happened that at the end of the line it is entering the file directory, like this: "./folder/archive.sas7bdat.gz,2020-03-04 11:21:59.648155603 -0300,2020-03-04 11:21 :59.845155836 -0300,2021-02-01 16:40:26.542568391 -0300,12716 ./folder/file.sas7bdat.gz". is there a way to remove it from the end? the rest is perfect.

Comment: `du -k "$f" | cut -f1`?

Comment: Thanksssss, Chepner

Answer (score -1):

This version works on my computer:

```
find . -exec stat --printf='%n,%x,%y,%z,' {} \; -exec du -k {} \; 2>&1 | tee output_sasdata_file_info.txt
```

Use the `--printf` option for `stat` to print the lines without the trailing newline character.

Comment: Returned the following error:
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.

Comment: I’ve updated the solution. This version must work.

Comment: I don't think "must" means what you think it does. You aren't passing a file name argument to `stat`.

Comment: He just ran the du -k command, the stat didn't. screenshot: https://ibb.co/C8zTN6k

Comment: Try the new version, please.

Comment: Same result as before :(

Comment: Wait a little bit more time, please. I’m solving…

Comment: No problem! I am very grateful that you are helping me.

Comment: Even assuming the command substitutions were evaluated for each file (they aren't; they're expanded before `find` even runs), you would need to pass `{}` to *both* commands explicitly. `find` only provides the current file as an implicit argument to the command that `-exec` itself runs.

Comment: I’ve add the final (I hope) version which  works on my computer.